Need help making iOS universal link work for React Native (Expo) app
TLDR; I've been trying to turn a subdomain of my site (share.joinorderly.com) into a universal link for weeks now and it just won't work. If I navigate to the page it loads fine but the app doesn't even attempt to open.
The app is built using Expo, and I'm currently just focusing on making an iOS deep link work (vast majority of my userbase).
I've done everything I can find online and ChatGPT can think of to make it work, including:

Adding deep link handling in my app (regular deep link using the orderly:// scheme works fine)
Updating the ios object in my app.json to include my domain as an associated domain

"ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.orderly.ios",
      "buildNumber": "1",
      "icon": "./images/orderly_icon_black.png",
      "associatedDomains": ["applinks:share.joinorderly.com"],
      "infoPlist": {
        "CFBundleURLTypes": [
          {
            "CFBundleURLSchemes": [
              "orderly"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },


Putting a apple-app-site-association file in the root of that subdomain AND in a folder called .well-known/

I made sure the file has no extension, but is being served in application/json format



Is there something else I need to be doing or checking to make this work? Any help at all is incredibly appreciated

nope, that's it. you can find the documentation here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains?language=objc
